# TFS 2010: Can't start collection

Tags: tfs

I am in the lucky situation to restore an old Team Foundation Server TFS 2010. I got a VM and everything is up and running. Now I tried to connect the DefaultCollection and I always get the message:

> "The host 'DefaultCollection" cannot be started. The snapshot
>   operation may have failed and needs to be restarted and completed
>   before the host can be started."

[image]

I tried to create a new collection and was successful. 
[image]

I also tried to "Rerun Job" in the Status tab. This service was again completed (Error message is strange because it's telling me something different?!?). 
[image]

I am also not able to detach the collection. Test connection works properly.

[image]

Repair was also not helpful.
[image]

Here the recent log files: https://www.dropbox.com/s/mdwa1ntjqnz4j6v/TFS.zip?dl=1

Here the result from the best practice analyzer: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9x2pilzwqmroecz/BPA.zip?dl=1

Any ideas? This drives me crazy and I can't find proper infomation or error codes for this problem to fix it.

Thx,
tro

Comment: Have you tried repairing it? https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ee349268%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: Yes, I tried. No luck :-(

Comment: Best practices analyzer? https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a863a496-3234-4962-b484-b5d95dbff7d1/tfs-2010-host-cannot-be-started-error?forum=tfssetup

Comment: It says the collection has SQL enterprise features enabled. Are you reinstalling it on a SQL server with SQL enterprise installed?

Comment: I attached the result from the best practice analyzer - strange: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9x2pilzwqmroecz/BPA.zip?dl=1. why I always see the DB connection problem? any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commonly the problem will be caused by below things:

- Database In Recovery
- Database Out-of-Sync
- Permission of Service Account is not right

So ,please try below items to narrow down the issue:

1. Check if your have restored all the databases, partial restoration
   of backups also can cause this issue. You can refer to the MSDN link
   of [list of TFS databases.](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/tfs/architecture/sql-server-databases)
2. Check the database connectivity manually. Check if you are able to
   connect to SQL database with the services account.
3. Try repairing the database by running command `DBCC CHECKDB` against all
   TFS databases.
4. Check if the TFS service account has the correct permission to
   access the database.

Please see [this article](http://www.ganshani.com/blog/2014/04/solved-tf246017-team-foundation-server-could-not-connect-to-the-database/) for details.

---

Besides, I find the error message "**The trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed**" in your log file. It has the possibility to cause your problem.

You can try to resolve the  trust relationship issue first, then try it again. Just try to [remove the computer from the domain and then rejoin the domain](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2771040/-the-trust-relationship-between-this-workstation-and-the-primary-domai). Please reference [this article](https://www.benday.com/2012/01/31/tfs-lab-management-vms-the-trust-relationship-between-this-workstation-and-the-primary-domain-failed/) for details.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the great summary. I will try it today or tomorrow and keep you updated. Appreciate your help.